# Fortran "Error:Expected expression in WRITE statement"

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I have gone through Fortran guide and tried sample programs, looked up the net for the error but nothing seemed to help.

My program is as follows:

```
    program TYPE_CHECK
    character(30), dimension(10)  :: buff
    integer, dimension(10) :: x
    integer :: i

    do i=1,10
        x(i) = i
    enddo

    write(*, "(I3)") (x(j), j=1,10)
    do j=1,10
    write(buff(j), *)(x(j)),
    *   'hi '
    enddo 
    do j=1,10
    write(*, 776) (buff(j))
 776    format(' NO OF ',A20, '=')
    enddo

    end program TYPE_CHECK
```

The above should give the output as follows :

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 NO OF            1 hi     =
 NO OF            2 hi     =
 NO OF            3 hi     =
 NO OF            4 hi     =
 NO OF            5 hi     =
 NO OF            6 hi     =
 NO OF            7 hi     =
 NO OF            8 hi     =
 NO OF            9 hi     =
 NO OF           10 hi     =
```

but instead gives the following errors:

```
myfoo2.F:12.30:

      write(buff(j), *)(x(j)),                                          
                          1
Error: Expected expression in WRITE statement at (1)
myfoo2.F:13.7:

      *   'hi '                                                          
       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Could you please tell where i have gone wrong. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

If you have been careful in your posting then this:

```
write(buff(j), *)(x(j)),
*   'hi '
```

is the source of the problem.  It is not properly formatted fixed-form source, nor is it properly continued free-form source.  I suggest you make sure that you understand what the difference between these forms is, and that you conform to the requirements of free-form source.  (Well, if you are using punched cards to prepare your sources for the compiler then fixed-form is more appropriate but that's relatively unusual in the 21st century.)

Change what you have to

```
write(buff(j), *)(x(j)), &
   'hi '
```

In fixed-form source the continuation character is in column 6 in the line which continues an unfinished expression.  Your snippet is obviously not fixed-form because your asterisk is directly underneath the `w` in `write` but in fixed-form source statements begin in column 7.

In free-form source lines are continued by appending an ampersand (`&`) to the end of the line being continued.

Comment: Well,it is supposed to be fixed-form . I tried putting the asterisk character in column 6 and writing the rest of the code withing column 7-72.It still continued to give the same error!

Comment: Putting the asterisk worked for the evaluating expressions but doesn't work for WRITE statement.

Comment: Don't write fixed-form source, it's 2014. At least, it's 2014 where I sit, what year is it with you ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe replace the  'hi '   with "hi "

helped me with a similar error